# Get deep learning output between 0 & 1

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm new in deep learning. My training data contains 3121 records & 137 input variables.This 137 variables I got after doing feature engineering from original 2K variables.

So I did standardization of variable between 0 & 1 & then used following model

```
model.add(Dropout(0.2, input_shape=(136,)))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(15,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='sigmoid',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
#model.add(Dense(60, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(30,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='sigmoid',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(15,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='sigmoid',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear',kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x,y,epochs=100,shuffle=True,verbose=2)
```

As my objective is to get minimu MSE so I used loss='mse'.My output varable in my test data contains value between 0 & 1, for example 0.35.But after fitting the model I'm getting predicted output as 0 & 1. Can you please suggest me what should I try to get predicted output between 0 & 1?

also tried activation function as 'relu' in my hidden layer & sigmoid in output layer. But still only 0 & 1 in my output

Below is the code I used to get predicted output

```
y_pred=model.predict_classes(x_test)
pred=pd.DataFrame(y_pred,columns=['predicted'])
pred.predicted.unique()
```

Comment: To return the probability of model predictions for binary classification problem, you need to use model.predict_prob(test_data) instead of model.predict_classes(test_data)

Comment: I would change all activations to ReLU and the activation at the last output to sigmoid, which is bounded between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `model.predict_proba(x_test)` instead of `model.predict_classes(x_test)`

**Usage:**

```
y_pred=model.predict_proba(x_test)
```

**Interpret y_pred:**

You are dealing with binary classification problem (Yes(1) or No(0)). Lets assume each input instances has K features.

Then,

`y_pred[0] = [Input feature 0,Input feature 1,...Input feature K-1]
 y_pred[1] = [probability of each instance belonging to class 1]`

Hence

`1- y_pred[1]` returns the probability for class 0